# How to set exact client size for overlapped window? (winapi)

Tags: windows, winapi, user-interface

I want to set anexact client size (say 300 x 300) when I create a normal 'overlapped' window.

There is the `AdjustWindowRectEx()` function where I can pass the desired client
area and get sizes that I can pass to CreateWindowEx but it says 
in the documentation that I should not use it for overlapped windows
and I do not understand why.

When I pass 300 x 300, I got 306 x 326 from it, and when I receive
`WM_SIZE`, the client size is 298 x 298 so it is 2 pixels too small.

How to create overlapped window with exact given client size?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My mistake in my case was the following:

```
AdjustWindowRectEx(&rect, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, WS_CLIPSIBLINGS, FALSE, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW);
```

Changing to this fixes it:

```
AdjustWindowRectEx(&rect, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, WS_CLIPSIBLINGS, FALSE, 0);
```

Comment: Your answer uses five function parameters but `AdjustWindowRectEx` takes only four.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why AdjustWindowRect isn't working (unless your client area contains a child window with a one-pixel border).

Note that you can use this function for overlapped windows.  The documentation says that you can't use the WS_OVERLAPPED style (I guess because it's value is zero), but you could use WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW.

As an alternative you can call GetWindowRect and GetClientRect, calculate the width/height of the borders (the difference between the width/height of the two rectangles), add these to the desired client size and set the window size.  I believe you can do this before the window is shown.

Comment: So, I understand you say that AdjustWindowrectEx just should work?????? (L8er I was doing some client size changing (becouse i blit to it and it shows that blit do not work if client is not aligned to 4 pixels - and I am slightly lost with it, but I think it is the reason, becouse it is probabbly not called - but will check it)

Comment: naay, It seem to be ok, I just get 306 325 from adjust then 298 298 in first WM_SIZE, still no reason for it

Comment: As I said in the last paragraph, if AdjustWindowRect isn't working for some reason you can calculate the border size yourself.

Comment: Border is 8 (2x4) (checked in paint.net and window width - client width gives 8 too) The problem is that for 300 AdjustWindoeRectEx gives 306 then CreateWindowEx gives 298 :/ (then GetWindowsRect and GetClientRect raports the same), looks like t is AdjustWindowEx fault